# Using Set /A in forfiles.exe in batch file

Tags: loops, batch-file, cmd

This is the weirdest thing.  I don't know forfiles is asynchronous or something, but this code seems easy and obvious to me, and is not working:

```
set a=0
forfiles /S /C "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE set /a a+=1 & echo !a!"
```

A simple counter I thought.  However, what is getting outputted is:
    `10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10`

And at the end `a` is still set to 0.

I have delayedexpansion enabled.  Why is this not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, `forfiles` calls for every file a new cmd with a new "fresh & empty" environment. The `1` from `10` is made by the `set` command, as you can see in this example:

```
forfiles /S /C "cmd /v:on /c if @isdir==FALSE set/a a+=1 >nul&echo !a!"
0
0
0
...
```

To get it working, use better a `for` loop:

```
for /r %%i in (*) do set /a a+=1 &echo !a!
```

Comment: `forfiles /s` recurses into subfolders, so an equivalent `for` loop needs `/r`.

Comment: `for /f %%i in ('dir /b /s /a:-D') do set /a a+=1 & echo !a!` will do it recursively.

Comment: That's good.  I knew I could do it with `for /r`, but I couldn't make sense of why the other method wasn't working.  Although I could make it work by `echoing 1` into a text file repeatedly and counting the lines.  But mainly I just couldn't get why it wasn't working.  In retrospect, your answer seems obvious...but hindsight..blah..blah.  Anyway, thanks for the clear answer.